# Espressif IDF override KConfig variable

Tags: makefile, esp8266, esp-idf

I need to flash a bunch of ESP boards that have a few different compile-time variables ( per board ) that are normally defined in a `Kconfig` file for a module.

Is there any way to pass some env variable or perhaps a command-line argument to `make` or `idf.py` that will update `sdkconfig`?  I can do that with `sed` no problem, but perhaps there's a better solution?

So I can use something like

```
for HOST in "a" "b" "c";
do
  echo "Plug board for host $HOST and press Enter"
  readline
  CONFIG_VAR_SMTH_HOST="${HOST}" make flash
  echo "Done"
done;
```